# password policy(not allowed special characters) between 18.04 and 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, ssh, password, openssh

I have two vm's, one with 18.04 and other with 20.04 on two different machines.
I used to configure password for the VM from machine. SHA512 is used for generating hash key for password. And generated hash is copied to /etc/shadow file on VM's.
When Hash key has special characters like ] ^ ; _ ^ [ = > @ VM running with 20.04 is not accepting the password where as vm running with 18.04 is accepting the password. Is there any limitation for the password policy on ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Using local function to get the salt value. only these special characters are present in the salt hash.
EX: $6$_^dsgE0M$hYaDVS39ga.Ji3z2aDMo0VfoYcJxg.zLBl/eXgZp3wh9WY0HEb35x8YB5xZO2dGCSexZTUsRbkkN9oBgJyKPR0

Comment: According to `man 5 crypt`, the salted hash for the `sha512crypt` algorithm should satisfy regex `\$6\$(rounds=[1-9][0-9]+\$)?[^$:\n]{1,16}\$[./0-9A-Za-z]{86}` so it looks like the only restriction on the salt is that it must be 1-16 characters not including `$`, `:`, or `\n`. However I can't find where in the glibc crypt source that gets validated.